# Motion of $2$ particles accelerated by a constant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I have the following problem:

[image]

As you can see, there are two particles of same mass $m$ connected by a massless string with length $2l$. Now a constant Force $F$ attacks at the string at Point $P$ and accelerates the string upwards, so that the particles move towards each other. The question is to find a formula for the horizontal acceleration (in $x$-Direction) of the particles.

My idea was the following:
The height $h$ of $P$ must accelerate in this form: $h(t)=\frac{a}{2}t^2$, since $F=2ma \Rightarrow h(t)=\frac{F}{4m}t^2$.
Let $\alpha$ be the deflection angle $(\measuredangle PmF)$ (<-hope you know what I mean). Then $\alpha(t)=\arcsin\frac{h(t)}{l}$.
If I draw a parallelogram of forces, I get the following equation:
$$F_x=\frac{F}{2\tan\alpha}$$ therefore
$$a_x(t)=\frac{F}{2m\tan\arcsin\frac{Ft^2}{4ml}}$$
Do you agree to this solution? Or did I miss something. They also said that it is possible to describe equations of motion as differential equations. Thank you for any hints and solutions.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767694/

Comment: You should have edited your original question rather than posting again.

Comment: *Do you agree to this solution?* The closure message on your first post of this problem explained that check-my-work questions are off-topic.

Comment: I just wanted to ask for help, but I didn't know that I have to read 1000 pages before which conditions have to be fulfilled